# How to pass username and password in authorization field?

Tags: http, authorization, unrealscript

In unrealscript, I'm attempting to connect to server using a TCPLink client I wrote. I can connect to the domain, but when I attempt to access a welcome message I receive a 401 error. What am I doing wrong in my authorization field?

Note: username and password are plain-text string variables filled in by the user

```
SendText("GET /crud/welcome HTTP/1.0"$chr(13)$chr(10));
SendText("Host: "$TargetHost$chr(13)$chr(10));
SendText("Authorization: "$USERNAME$":"$PASSWORD$chr(13)$chr(10));
SendText("Connection: Close"$chr(13)$chr(10));
SendText(chr(13)$chr(10));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read RFC 2617.